# Connection not closed after test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, node-postgres

I have a simple postgres.js wrapper file.

```
const pg =  require("pg")
const pool = new pg.Pool({ connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL });

function close() {
  return pool.end()
}

module.exports = {
    end: pool.end,
    close
};
```

Running a jest testcase that utilizes the postgres library above, like so:

```
const postgres = require("./path/to/postgres.js");

describe("Foo", () => {
  afterAll(() => { 
    return postgres.end();
  })

  it(...)
});
```

Will yield the "This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests." error message and hangs there.

However, if I change the line `postgres.end()` to `postgres.close()`, it correctly closes the DB connection and jest terminates after the test is done.

My question is that doesn't `close` and `end` functionally does the same thing? Why does one close the connection but the other doesn't?

Comment: `end: pool.end.bind(pool)`? Given the difference, I'd guess a `this` binding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `end` function is just executing the `pool.end` and not returning it as a promise, so it's not similar. 
For a better visualization, your current code is basically doing this:

```
    function close() {
        return pool.end()
    }

    function end() {
      pool.end()
    }

module.exports = {
    end,
    close
};
```

Comment: Why do you think the promise the not returned ?